# Autocompletion in Comments xcode 7

Tags: swift2, xcode7.3

Is there a way to turn off autocompletion in comments?. I don't really know if this should be ON in the first place. What's the point to have autocompletion in comments anyway?, it's ridiculous.[image: autocompletionIncomments]

I'm using xcode 7.3 in swift.

Comment: It's not ridiculous: it's useful for writing *documentation* comments. But I agree it should be an option in Xcode's preferences.

Comment: I disagree. Useful when those comments would be for documenting a function/method/class, but not useful when adding comments like TODO, MARK or other more generic comments. As you can see in the snapshot, autocompletion is suggesting whatever it pleased to suggest and I can assure you, it had nothing to do with what is at the left part of that // TODO text.